# How to configure alpha.nvim?

Tags: lua, neovim

I have an `init.lua` file that contains: `require "user.setup.alpha"` as in:

```
  require "user.options"    
  require "user.keymaps"    
  require "user.autocmds"    
  require "user.commands"    
  require "user.plugins"    
  require "user.colorschemes"    
  require "user.setup.cmp"    
  require "user.setup.alpha"    
  require "user.setup.telescope"    
  require "user.setup.treesitter"    
  require "user.setup.autopairs"    
  require "user.setup.comment"    
  require "user.setup.gitsigns"    
  require "user.setup.neo-tree"    
  require "user.setup.bufferline"    
  require "user.setup.better-escape"    
  require "user.setup.notify"    
  require "user.setup.lualine"    
  require "user.setup.whichkey"    
  require "user.setup.hop"    
  require "user.setup.lsp"    
  require "user.setup.dap.debug"    
  require "user.setup.semantic"
```

And the `alpha.lua` file is:

```
 local status_ok, alpha = pcall(require, "alpha")    
 if not status_ok then                                        
   return    
 end    
     
 alpha.setup { 
   theme = "dashboard"                                          
 }
```

But when I type in the `:source` command it shows an error message.

I could not copy paste the error message. So I wrote it roughly down here:

```
Expected table got nil
```

I also tried having this line instead:

```
alpha.setup()
```

But the error remained the same.

The plugin is installed with:

```
use "goolord/alpha-nvim"
```

I'm on `NVIM v0.6.1`

Comment: Could you please give your full init.lua? I can help

Comment: I added it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the issue with my following configuration:

```
  local status_ok, alpha = pcall(require, "alpha")                                       
  if not status_ok then
    return
  end
                                                                                                                                                 
 local theme_ok, alpha_theme = pcall(require, "alpha.themes.startify")                                                                          
 if not theme_ok then                                                                                                                           
   return                                                                                                                                       
 end

 alpha.setup(alpha_theme.config)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a default theme you could just add this from the docs to your `lazy.lua` and create the same folder/module structure in your project:

```
    {
    goolord/alpha-nvim',
       config = function ()
    require'alpha'.setup(require'alpha.themes.dashboard'.config)
end },
```

- then use Lua tables `{}` and which-key plugin to create custom mappings and build out a dashboard/UI

exmaple: `<space>F` will open a new menu from Alpha main menu

```lua
dashboard = {

   buttons = {
         {"" "new file","<space>f"},
         {"icon", "event" ,"command to execute event"},
 
},
alpha.setup(dashboard)
```

call the table from Alpha setup and should be good.
Lua is super dynamic so there will be many ways to troubleshoot the Dashboard
https://github.com/goolord/alpha-nvim/blob/main/doc/alpha.txt
Hope this helps or gives some ideas!